# Wordpress query_posts orderby meta queries

Tags: wordpress, posts

This should be simple, but I just can't pinned down a good example of the correct syntax to do this.

**I want to filter my posts by the meta_queries but order them by the specified meta_key.**

When I run the code as is it results an infinite loop. I only included the problem code the other code is your basic Loop code that the query_post runs in.

Also all the PHP variables are correct and are not the problem.

```
        $args2 = array(
            'meta_key' => '_count-views_all',
            //'meta_value' => $id,
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => $sortOrder,
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'meta_query' => array(  
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'contributorid1',
                            'value' => $id,
                            'compare' => '='
                            ),

                        array(
                            'key' => 'contributorid2',
                            'value' => $id,
                            'compare' => '='
                            )
                        )
        );
        $posts = query_posts($args2); 
    }
```

Here is another query that works completely without issue to cross reference. The two run on the same page but the are nested in an if else statement

```
        $args1 = array(
            //'meta_key' => 'contributorid1',
            //'meta_value' => $id,
            'order' => $sortOrder,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'contributorid1',
                            'value' => $id,
                            'compare' => '='
                            ),

                        array(
                            'key' => 'contributorid2',
                            'value' => $id,
                            'compare' => '='
                            )
                        )
        );
        $posts = query_posts($args1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The query looks reasonable to me. The only method by which I see this running into an infinite loop is if this query runs within the post loop. When you use query_posts as you are, it will change the state of the global $wp_query, which is used for the pointer in the main posts loop.

If it kept hitting query_posts within the loop, it would continually change the state of the global $wp_query object, and reset the pointer for the current post to the first post of that new query, which would ultimately create the infinite loop.

If this code is being used within the loop, I'd recommend instead using something like

```
$query = new WP_Query($args2);
if ($query->have_posts()) { ... etc; }
```

If you need to then set up global post data within it, be sure to use `wp_setup_postdata` or `$query->the_post()` and `wp_reset_postdata` or `wp_reset_query` appropriately when you are finished using that post as the global post information.

Comment: Yeah I looked into that, but I had other issues, So i decided to try running it inside a Foreach loop. Which is what this is now running in since I am running it after I run the main loop for the page. I know it seems backwards but the loop works and lets me sort by date, and alphabetical just not by this mviewed query.

Comment: Hmm.. I did a query almost exactly like that recently, and had no real issue. Have you reviewed the actual query that WordPress is generating? I've attempted to do a similar query with one of my clients (where I had already been doing that exact thing, but ordering by a timestamp integer instead) with no issue.

Comment: I put up a second piece of information.  I looked at the query it only seems to break if I add the meta key and order by meta_value_num.

Comment: Doing some further testing it appears that the query doesn't like having both arguments of meta_key and meta_queries. Is there another way to do this in query_posts?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Here's an example of a query I wrote that is functional, and similar to yours:

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'posts_per_page' => $num_events,
        'no_found_rows' => true,
        'meta_key' => '_date',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_date',
                'value' => time(),
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                'compare' => '>'
            )
        ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    query_posts($args);

Comment: Progress is being made, so looking at yours I noticed the only major difference is that mine had to meta queries. I took one out and the relation out and it works without issue, However I am wondering how would I get it to work with two meta_queries?